# Describe the diffrence between the following two problems and give an example of a physical situation which may be modeled by each equation

Tags: laplace-transform, dirac-delta

$y'' + y =\mu_\pi    \big(t\big)$

$y''+y= \delta (x- \pi )$

wih initial conditions:

$y \big(0\big) =0$

$y' \big(0\big) =0$

It is obvious to me that the first equation is a Heaviside distribution and the second is a dirac  delta funtion. I am not sure if that is the difference between them or I need to perform Laplace transforms to see the difference. Also I am not sure of any physical situation which would describe these eqautions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have your lectures or textbook mentioned "forcing functions"? Also, do you know the graphs of the heaviside and dirac delta functions?

Comment: Does the Heaviside distribution have a discontinous forcing funcition?

Comment: The Heaviside distribution is discontinuous, and is a forcing function in this equation.